# incorporate other py files in django views and render in html

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am new to working with django as a local server.
Thus I don't get the logic.

How do I incorporate my own customfile.py files in the views? How can I include them to have the results from the customfile1-calculations outputted to the views and rendered in the index.html?

Let's say I have:

```
project1
-app1
--views.py
--customfile1.py
---templates\app1\index.html
```

How and what do I need to change in the views.py or perhaps somewhere else, too?
I don't want to have the whole logic of the whole app written in the views.py adn rather separated into sub-files.

Answer (score 1):

In your `views.py` you can simply import whatever functions or variables you have in `customfile1.py`.

**views.py**

```py
from .customfile1 import my_function

# Or like this to import everything
from . import customfile1

customfile1.my_function()
```

Then use those functions in views.py and send your data to a template from there

**Another alternative**

You can also create a folder instead

```
project1
---app1/
------views/
---------__init__.py
---------customfile1.py
---------customfile2.py
---templates\app1\index.html
```

And then in **init**.py do:

```
from .customfile1 import *
from .customfile2 import *
```